# Trying to add a logic hook to suiteCRM when creating or updating a task

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

This is my first try into coding for sugarCRM / suiteCRM.

I should say I've been coding for Wordpress for nearly 10 years now, but I'm completely lost now I'm starting to dig into suiteCRM.

I've read that you can add a logic hook to modify the data after saving it to the database, but I don't know where to start...

Imagine I create a task for today, july 7th, related to a client I use to visit every 2 months, so there's a field in Accounts named "Visiting frequency". I'd like to add a future date (july 7th + 60 days = september 7th aprox) into the task's "Future Visiting Date" field, so I can use it to create that particular future task via Workflow.

What I'm trying to do is to calculate a field in tasks (Future visiting date), that equals to the amount of days on the accounts module's field (Visiting frequency) added to the task's own Date field.

I've been able to make it work, using the following layout:

Inside `\custom\modules\Tasks\logic_hooks.php`

```
<?php

$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array();

$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(
    1, //Processing index. For sorting the array.
    'future_task_date_on_task_creation', //Label. A string value to identify the hook.
    'custom/modules/Tasks/future_visit_date.php', //The PHP file where your class is located.
    'before_save_class', //The class the method is in.
    'future_visit_date' //The method to call.
);

?>
```

Inside \custom\modules\Tasks\future_visit_date.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class before_save_class {

    function future_visit_date($bean, $event, $arguments) {
        $bean->rhun_fecha_sig_c = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
    }

}

?>
```

With this setup, the Future Visiting Date gets filled with the calculated date.

I've also read that this setup is not advised, and that I should use the Extension Framework and put the first file in this path:

```
/custom/Extension/modules/Tasks/Ext/LogicHooks/<file>.php
```

But I can't make it work.

Do I have to create the LogicHooks folder if it's not there?
Which filename should I assign to this file?
Do I have to change something else inside the code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create the LogicHooks directory if it doesn't exist.  The PHP file can be called anything you like.

/custom/Extension/modules/Tasks/Ext/LogicHooks/MyLogicHookFile.php

Define your logic hooks in this file as before.

```
<?php

$hook_version = 1; 
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array();

$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(
    1, //Processing index. For sorting the array.
    'future_task_date_on_task_creation', //Label. A string value to identify the hook.
    'custom/modules/Tasks/future_visit_date.php', //The PHP file where your class is located.
    'before_save_class', //The class the method is in.
    'future_visit_date' //The method to call.
);
```

Then run a repair and rebuild from the Admin panel.

The main advantage to using the Extension framework is that it allows multiple developers to add components to a Sugar instance without worrying about overwriting existing code.
More info can be found about it in the [Developer Guide](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Extension_Framework/)